# What is the correct path for Edge of the Forest?

Tags: evoland-2

I'm trying to find the correct path to unlock the ghost hiding in there. What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no ghost there, try exploring other places, you should only go to the edge of the forest once you found all 6 ghosts and spoke to the guardian. Only then you can leave by the edge as if it was a normal forest of the lost puzzle.

EDIT: it's no longer a puzzle after you found all of them, to the left it's a chest, the right path leads to nothing, apparently, and the north is the way forward.

Comment: You should add in extra information as edits, rather then posting as a comment. Comments are for asking for clarification, or for adding information to posts that **are not your own**.